# Disable ServiceStack 304s?

Tags: jquery, http, caching, http-caching, servicestack

I have an IService that when jQuery.ajax requests it in IE, ServiceStack always returns a 304 and doesn't execute my service. I've tried ResponseFilters, switching to RestServiceBase, and returning a 200 via HttpResult. What am I missing?

**Solved.**

ServiceStack is working as it should.  I had tried adding the CacheControl: no-cache header using ResponseFilters, but to my consternation I kept getting 304s. Then I realized that was because the original response withouth the Cache-Control header was in IE's cache, hence the 304s. Clearing IE's cache got everything working :-)

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer @rothkko.